# How to create an instance of a nested class that is defined outside of the enclosing one?

Tags: c++

If I define a nested class and then create an instance like this:

```
class A  
{   
    class B  
    {  
        ...
    };
    B b; 
};
```

everything is ok. But if I just declare B inside of A and define it outside, I can't create an instance of B, probably because the compiler don't know how much space the instance of B will need. But code is not much readable when you define a class inside another. Is there a way to make this work?

```
class A  
{
    class B;
    B b;
};
class A::B
{
    ...
};
```

Comment: If all you have is a forward declaration (which is an incomplete type, as you said), you'll need a pointer. If you want to define something outside of the class, put the declarations for the members in there and do `void A::B::foo() {}`.

Comment: yes, but even when you put only the declarations of the nested class inside and define outside, I think it makes the enclosing class less readable. thank you very much, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just define class B, then define an instance of it in A.

```
class B
{
}
class A
{
   B memberB;
}
```

Or you can forward declare it:

```
class B;
class A
{
   B memberB;
}
class B
{
}
```

Truly nested classes are rarely needed and not very useful at all.

Comment: maybe it's not really that useful, but it would restrict someone from instancing the nested class outside, right?

Comment: It's pretty hacky and I would avoid it, but you can always give B a private constructor and make A a friend.

Comment: No. They can still do: $ A::B instanceOfB; Just because B is nested it does not mean that you can't create an instance of it. Why don't you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your second code sample is neither correct, nor compilable. You cannot declare and instance-type variable of an unfinished type. The best you can do is a reference or a pointer. Your first sample is correct.

Comment: @user2036161 I just wanted to make so that the classes organization would match what they represent in real world. In this case B would be something tha only makes sense if it exists inside of A. But it does not matters that much.. thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

When you use a class type as a member, the concrete class needs to be known. That's why your second case doesn't work. A work around is to use pointer to `B`:

```
#include <memory>
class A  
{
    class B;
    std::unique_ptr<B> b;
};
class A::B
{    
};
```